# Autodesk forge viewer js dependencies storing in local project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am working with Autodesk viewer using angular and typescript. I am using https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.css - (For CSS) and https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.js - (For JS).

But I want to download these files to store and use from the project folder. It seems like downloading and adding only these files won't do the job as viewer3D.js references more online js files.

Can I get all the files which are needed to view locally.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a few other files required by the Viewer, but per [license](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.js), you should use them from Autodesk server:

```
// Autodesk Forge Viewer Usage Limitations:
// 
// The Autodesk Forge viewer can only be used to view files generated by
// Autodesk Forge services. The Autodesk Forge Viewer JavaScript must be
// delivered from an Autodesk hosted URL.
```